# Convert number into date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, string-formatting

I have date in without "/" in text field and it is in `mm/dd/yy` format. We received input in this format 03292014. I want to get month,date and year from this number like 03/29/2014

```
var m = new Date(3292014*1000)

console.log(m.toGMTString())
```

Comment: There are so many answers about creating `Date` objects from strings and formatting a date string from a Javascript `Date` object here on SO. You should try to search a little harder, you can't miss them.

Comment: On way could be: use a regex to get the parts, build the date out of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this :

```
var m = '03292014'.match(/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/);
var d = new Date(m[3], m[1] - 1, m[2]);
```

Or convert the input into a standard "YYYY-MM-DD" format :

```
var d = new Date('03292014'.replace(
    /(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '$3-$1-$2'
));
```

Specs : http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15.

---

According to [Xotic750's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116192/convert-number-into-date-using-javascript#comment33551834_22116252), in case you just want to change the format :

```
var input = '03292014';
input = input.replace(
    /(\d\d)(\d\d)\d\d(\d\d)/, '$1/$2/$3'
);
input; // "03/29/14"
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the components from the input, then you can create a `Date` object from them. Example:

```
var input = '03292014';

var year = parseInt(input.substr(4), 10);
var day = parseInt(input.substr(2, 2), 10);
var month = parseInt(input.substr(0, 2), 10);

var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
```

Comment: Well,  this is the simplest way to do this but considering that OP may get some other format in future, it is better to write  a function that takes input as input string, input format and output format.  Just a thought,  usually that is my approach.  Cheers!

Comment: If the OP is just looking to format `03292014` to `03/29/2014` then there isn't actually any need to use `Date` at all. A `splice` or `slice` only solution would be adequate. :)

Comment: @Xotic750: Yes, if that is what the OP wants to do. The code example in the question suggests that a `Date` object is the desired result.

Comment: I think you are just far too kind. ;)

Comment: @Xotic750 The title is very misleading here.

Comment: Indeed: neither the input or output are a `number`, lack of any effort I feel. :)