# How to convert 112889 (mmddyy) to 11/28/89 or 11/28/1989

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

How do we convert this unformatted date of 112889 (mmddyy) to specific format like  11/28/89?

```
console.log(new Date('112889'))
// I got this: Sat Jan 01 112889 00:00:00 GMT+0800
```

I have searched anywhere in google concerning this but found none specific answers.

Reference searches:

1. https://forums.asp.net/t/1987249.aspx?How+can+i+convert+Date+1365715800000+format+to+MM+dd+yyyy
2. [Convert number into date using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116192/convert-number-into-date-using-javascript)

Im also thinking about momentjs formatting but couldn't find any doc about this or did i only missed it

Comment: Have a look at moment.js library. https://momentjs.com/docs/ . moment("112889", "MMDDYY");

Comment: sure! @SubirKumarSao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the momentjs library you can specify what format your input string will come i.e. MMDDYY in this case.

```js
var d = new moment("112889", "MMDDYY");
document.getElementById('dated').innerText = d.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="dated"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look moment.js library. try this code

```
    var date = moment('112889',"MMDDYY").format('MM/DD/YY');
    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library and if you know that your input is always going to be of `mmddyy` format, you can do something like this:

```
var str = '112889';
var arr = str.match(/.{1,2}/g); // Splits string into 2 character chunks
var d = new Date(arr[2],arr[0],arr[1]);
console.log(d);
```

But this is quite not correct since if you give a string like `112804`, JS (or anyone for that matter) will not know if it is 1904 or 2004 and it'll pick up 1904. In that case, you should specify explicitly:

```
var str = '112896';
var arr = str.match(/.{1,2}/g); // Splits string into 2 character chunks
var d = new Date(arr[2], arr[0], arr[1]); // new Date(yy,mm,dd);
var presentYear = Number((new Date()).getFullYear());
var dateYear = Number(d.getFullYear());
if (presentYear >= dateYear + 100) { // If adding 100 to year makes it greater than present year, then move to 2000s
  d = new Date('20' + arr[2], arr[0], arr[1]);
}
console.log(d);
```